# Webview looses focus after showing a dialog

Tags: android, webview, focus, android-webview

I am showing a dialog after opening a website in a webview. Now after I display the dialog, the webView becomes non-responsive - meaning I cannot insert anything in it or click a button.

Here is the code I use for showing the dialog:

```
android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog.Builder inputAlert = new android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        inputAlert.setMessage(message);
        userInput = new EditText(this);
        inputAlert.setView(userInput);
        inputAlert.setPositiveButton("Submit", clickListener);
        inputAlert.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                dialog.dismiss();
                webview.requestFocus();
            }
        });
        AlertDialog alertDialog = inputAlert.create();
        alertDialog.show();
```

I also used `webview.requestFocus()` but it doesn't change anything.
Here is how I init the webview:

```
webview.requestFocus(View.FOCUS_DOWN);
webview.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
android.webkit.CookieManager.getInstance().removeAllCookie();
webview.loadUrl("https://someurl.com");
```

Comment: "after I display the dialog, the webView becomes un responsive" - do you mean, after the dialog is dismissed? Does this happen when you click Submit, or Cancel, or both?

Comment: @LarsH this is happening after I dismiss the dialog - submit and cancel, it doesnt matter. Do you have an idea what can cause this?

Comment: @DarkoPetkovski I know this is a long shot, but did you ever find a fix for this 3 year and 4 month old question? I'm having a similar problem myself.